# Bigcommerce Cart page and Checkout page ingnoring themes fonts style

Tags: html, css, fonts, bigcommerce

I have big commerce website and here is the website link https://www.taoaccents.com
I am using the simple theme for the website.
I have upload custom fonts and call it into styles.css with correct paths below is the code of the fonts which I have called into my styles.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaReg';
    src: url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.eot');
    src: url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.svg#ProximaNovaReg') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaSbold';
    src: url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaSbold.eot');
    src: url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaSbold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaSbold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaSbold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaSbold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaSbold.svg#ProximaNovaSbold') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaBold';
    src: url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.eot');
    src: url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.svg#ProximaNovaBold') format('svg');
}
```

its working on website fine but there are some pages on which the fonts not working the pages cart and checkout processing all steps

https://www.taoaccents.com/cart.php

https://www.taoaccents.com/checkout.php

please suggest me where I have done wrong things.

Comment: You need to use https in your urls

Comment: Your site is on `https` and you provided the url for static files with `http`. So change it to `https`.

Comment: @Gerard, thanks, wow your suggestion is very appreciated. Can you make an answer and I will vote it up thanku so much?

Comment: @aavrug, you are right sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `https` instead of `http` in your URLs like so

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ProximaNovaReg';
src: url('https://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.eot');
src: url('https://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('https://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('https://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.woff') format('woff'),
url('https://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.ttf') format('truetype'),        url('https://www.taoaccents.com/template/Styles/fonts/ProximaNovaReg.svg#ProximaNovaReg') format('svg');
}
```